# My C# Regex pattern fails to match text between tags

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following raw text:

```
<target xml:lang="ar">افصل الدائرة عن مخرج جهاز التنفس،\nواترك خراطيم المهايئ الزفيري متصلة.</target>
```

And i'm interested in the text between the `<target xml:lang="ar">` and the end tag `</target>` I realise it's a bad idea to match HTML or XML tags with Regexm but these tags are constants, as in there will never be added attributes (they are generated by some tool and will always be same)

Now I realise there's a million way to skin a cat, and that I can do a substring match to get text between > and < but it's really frustrating me why the pattern I chose isn't working, even though the online regex testers do match the text such as http://regexstorm.net/tester.

Here's my code:

`string pattern = @"<target xml:lang=""ar"">(.*?)</target>";`

```
string line = @"<target xml:lang=""ar"">افصل الدائرة عن مخرج جهاز التنفس،\nواترك خراطيم المهايئ الزفيري متصلة.</target>"
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(line, pattern))
{
    // Split the Arabic text from the xml tags
    string arabicTransMatch = match.Groups[1].Value;
    string[] xmlTags = line.Split(new string[] { arabicTransMatch }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    ...
}
```

Thanks heaps for your help all

Cheers,

Simon

Comment: You need to use `(?s)` or `Regex.Singleline` option to make `.` matches new line.

Comment: Have a look at http://regex101.com.  You can use it to test your regular expressions against test strings and see in realtime if they are matching as you expect.

Comment: @JeffPrince: Please don't suggest regex101 for .NET regex. Different flavors have quirks specific to each of them.

Comment: @nhatdh Could clarify what you mean.  I haven't noticed any problems using regx101.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the frowned upon usage of Regex with Tags, I will answer my own question by stating that I've shied away from using Regex, and simply used the Substring method;

```
int startIndex = line.IndexOf(">") + 1;
line = line.Substring(startIndex, line.IndexOf("<", startIndex));
```

As for fixing the Regex matching issue, the advice given by @nhahtdh in regards to the SingleLine option did the trick.

Thanks for your comments guys.

Comment: You may have missed the point about Regex with Tags.  You should use a parser, which does a better job at catching all cases.  Using string methods is probably the most primitive thing you can use, verbose, and not scalable to multiple cases.  Regex will give you much greater coverage, but has its place.

Comment: @ergonaut would you be able to link to an example with Parsers? I'm afraid I didn't quite catch what you mean. Thanks mate